# Bash script with condition

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, terminal, imagemagick

I want to create a Bash script executable for the terminal.

Depending on the number of files in a directory it should execute an ImageMagick command for a image sequence.

This is my try, but in the `if` conditions I got an error like this

```
date.sh: line 5: [: missing `]'
date.sh: line 7: [: missing `]'
```

The script:

```
#! /bin/bash
f=$(find . -name "0001_*_L.jpg" | wc -l) 

for i in {1..$f}; do 
     if [ "$f" -lt 10]; then
      fz=000
     elif [ "$f" -lt 100]; then
      fz=00
     else fz=0  
    fi  

    echo $fz $i
    convert *_$fz$i_L.png +append L/$i_L.png
    convert *_$fz$i_R.png +append R/$i_R.png
done
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You need to add a space before closing your square brackets `]`

Comment: After your syntax with the `]` is fixed, your ImageMagick commands may still not work.. but then please ask another question tagged with `imagemagick`  :-)

Comment: Try running this... `printf "%04d %04d %04d" 7 77 777`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has this line for the *'if'* condition:

```
if [ "$f" -lt 10]; then
```

You should change it to:

```
#               +--- (extra space here!)
#               |
#               v
if [ "$f" -lt 10 ]; then
```

The same should happen on your other line using *'elif'*:

```
elif [ "$f" -lt 100 ]; then
```

This is a requirement of the `if [ ... ]; then` syntax: the `[` and `]` need to have these extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I find this a nicer way to zero pad...

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..101}; do
   # Calculate a zero-padded $i
   zpi=$(printf "%04d" $i)
   echo $zpi
done
```

**Output**

```
0001
0002
...
0008
0009
0010
0011
0012
...
0098
0099
0100
0101
...
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses, this is a much smarter way then i thought with the %04d. Sometimes it could be much easier

this is my code i got running

```
#! /bin/bash

f=$(find . -name "0001_*_L.jpg" | wc -l) 
echo $f

i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$f" ]; do

fz=$(printf "%04d" $i)
echo $fz

convert "*_${fz}_L.jpg" +append "L/${fz}_scrL.jpg"
convert "*_${fz}_R.jpg" +append "R/${fz}_scrR.jpg"

i=$(($i + 1))
done
```